# How to store id on hidden value in secure way

Tags: php, html, mysql, security, hash

I am facing a problem. I store the id in hidden value like

```
<input id="send" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">
<input type="hidden" value="update" name="action">
<input type="hidden" value="$ticket_id" name="ticket_id">
```

When user clicked **crtl+shift+i**  they can see the code like

```
<input id="send" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">
<input type="hidden" value="update" name="action">
<input type="hidden" value="40" name="ticket_id">
```

And if they change the **ticket_id** 's value to another number,
that will update another **ticket's information**,
but my system structure is to allow updates by the person who posted the ticket.

So how can I solve this problem? Please give some advise.

**Update**
I will check the user id before update and use `mcrypt_encrypt()` and `mcrypt_decrypt()`. 
This is my current code

```
$secret_key = "fd4f8dasdjia5s5fd856d2s2";
#Create the initialization vector for added security.#
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
#Encrypt $string#
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $ticket_id, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
<input type='hidden' value='$encrypted_string' name='ticket_id'>
```

This is what i saw on client side

```
M�l ���e�/^�u�&22�)L�w�X�
```

This is the code when i **decrypted** the ticket_id

```
$secret_key = "fd4f8dasdjia5s5fd856d2s2";
// Create the initialization vector for added security.
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
         $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $ticket_id, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
         echo $decrypted_string;die;
```

But I get this when I **echo** `$decrypted_string`
    `~~��+A�W�`����hA%l��JYT�YY���͝��j0K1�r-�R�S`Z��zE�h�tLQ8�`

I didnt get  **40**, why?

Comment: Use a session variable to pass the ticket ID instead of passing it over hidden parameters. Session variables are hard to spoof.

Comment: Or validate ownership of the ticket on the backend? Then people are only able to change tickets that they own. And they should be able to do that anyway?

Comment: That's because of the IV value. You can use this class from "https://gist.github.com/chrisns/3992815".

Comment: You can try here: http://www.phpaes.com/index.php#encrypt

Comment: Hi, @Mir, you said is IV Value problem, but how to use the class?Im sorry,I am newbie of PHP, i dont really understand

Comment: Its really simple. You can copy the code from here: http://www.phpaes.com/index.php#encrypt and use the hex value for your ticket_id

Comment: @Rasika sessions are not hard to spoof if the webhosting is saving all sessions within one directory for all virtaul hosts.

Answer (score 3):

You have to verify server side that the user own the ticket, so for example with a SQL query :

```
"SELECT * FROM ticket_user WHERE user_id = :user_id AND ticket_id = :ticket_id"
```

If its return a row then you can process to the update else throw an error.

In addition to that you can also encrypt/decrypt the ticket_id.

Comment: Yes the server has to validate and check the incoming data of every single request. One can never trust the data sent by a client.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use access controls and application logic. Only let a user access resources they have explicit permission to access.
2. If you need to prevent a form attribute from being tampered with, also include a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).

```
<?php
    $id = 40;
    $some_long_secret_key = 
        "\xc4\x28\x06\xca" . "\xaa\x9c\x45\x66" .
        "\x61\xdd\xeb\x40" . "\x13\x59\x86\xb6" .
        "\xbb\xe6\xeb\x13" . "\x56\xdc\x17\x8d" .
        "\x5f\x4e\x3b\x79" . "\x1e\x98\x28\xb3";
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo intval($id); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="id_mac" value="<?php 
    echo hash_hmac('sha256', $id, $some_long_secret_key); 
?>" />
```

Also, before you implement any of the encryption suggestions, read this piece on [url encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php). TL;DR don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can secure your id using various encrypt methods in PHP. So every time first convert your id field in to encrypted value. then pass it to view or set as a value in text field.

And when you got back that encrypted value then first decrypt that value so you will get real id.

Comment: Hi, I have already updated my question, please have a look, thanks

Comment: Encryption is a bad idea. If a known encrypted value is used then somebody can use that value elsewhere (aka "consult the oracle"). e.g. if they know they have the ID 5 on an unrelated page, they can then use that encrypted value elsewhere that requires a 5.

Comment: @SilverlightFox then tell me your idea. 'if they know they have the ID 5 ' : tell me how they know in this case.

Comment: Simply validate the ID server side. It is OK to have a hidden ID in the form if the server validates that the current user has permission to update the object with that ID.

Comment: @SilverlightFox In the form hidden ID is an encrypted. How you validate it from server side?

Comment: Simple - Don't encrypt it. Even if it was encrypted, the server must have the key anyway.

Answer (score -1):

you can handle this in javascript.You can pass your object to javascript function and then utilise values inside javascript,and in your live environment deploy minified javascript files.

You can also consider storing this information into session.

Comment: Using a different client-side storage mechanism doesn't really solve the problem. It needs to be a server-side solution.

Answer (score -2):

you can encrypt the value before storing it in the hidden field 
then decrypt the value when you want to use it 
you can use mcrypt_encrypt() and mcrypt_decrypt() see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php)

Comment: Hi, I have already updated my question, please have a look, thanks

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't recommend storing ids in session variables. You will encounter other problems. If the user opens another ticket in another tab (tab 2) and switches back to tab 1 and submits a form. Your code will update whatever is the latest ticket id stored in the session.

Here is what you should do:

1. Add Restriction: Allow authorized users to access tickets which belong to them.
2. Encrypt: Use [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) encryption and encrypt your ticket_id. You will be able encode before rendering and decode after the form is submitted. AES will change the output every time you render it (even if it's the same id). It would be a long unique unpredictable string.

Hope this helps.